# HLSL Copying sampler2D colors to RWTexture2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl, fragment-shader

New to shader coding, so no Idea if this is possible. I'm trying to copy colors(basically the texture) from a sampler2D. That being the main texture on a Unity-engine material. This copy texture is then used on the next frame together with the main texture. I do this instead of using two textures or merging them because the texture is a render-texture and therefore dynamic. The shader-type is a fragment shader and not using any c# scripts (which I want to keep that way if possible).
(Sorry for any bad spelling, my English isn't the greatest).

Already tried to write to the texture, but it remained black completely. I probably messed something up there. I also tried to use a float4 array, but that was, to nobody's surprise too big. Using multiple arrays would result in unity canceling the compilation.